# Snubber to protect a VO2223A optical triac switching 0.5A @24 vac?

Tags: inductive, snubber, solenoid-valve

Is a snubber necessary to protect a VO2223A optical triac to occasionally control a valve that draws .5 amp @ 24 vac 60 hertz. What would be the R/C values if required?

Answer (score 2):

A full procedure for this task can be found in [Fairchild Semiconductor AN-3008](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-3008.pdf).  Going from that app note, as simply as I possibly can:

- dV/dt(s) -- static rate-of-voltage-rise induced turn-on from transients is unlikely to be an issue due to the transient attenuation of the 24VAC transformer, unless long lines are present that can cross-couple transients into the triac circuit.  The use of a gate-to-MT1 (pins 5 and 6 on the VO2223A) resistor or capacitor should not be needed as the 210V/µs dV/dt(s) rating of the VO2223A output triac is quite high; if this problem does occur in practice, a 100nF, X2 rated capacitor can be used gate-to-MT1 to suppress it.
- dI/dt(c) -- the commutating current rate-of-fall is important for proper turn off of the triac, as it interacts with the dV/dt(c) of the triac. Fortunately, your load (0.5A at 60Hz) is not a stringent one, with a dI/dt(c) of .00018 A/µs.
- dV/dt(c) -- the commutating voltage rate-of-rise is the main factor a snubber is designed to control, as failing to control this leads to an inability to turn *off* the triac.  However, the correct snubber parameters depend on the *inductance* of the load, as that is important in determining the damping factor of the snubber, which should be kept around 0.3 to best suppress dV/dt(c) in a low voltage circuit.  Also keep in mind that the conduction time for the triac should be upwards of 5τ in order to allow the snubber capacitor to discharge.
- Procedurally, based on the Snubber Physics section:

  1. I'd measure the inductance of your coil -- any ol' LCR meter will do.
  2. Pick a capacitor value based on whatever X2 rated capacitors you have available (I'm only using X2 here due to transient threats from long lines -- if that's not an issue, you can use a regular polyester film cap) -- anything between oh, 47nF and 470nF should be a workable starting point.
  3. Compute the resistor value based on the damping factor equation given in AN-3008 page 6, and compare it to the minimum values in Table 1 on page 7 -- if you get less than 39 ohms, decrease the capacitor value to the next lower one available to you and try again.
  4. TIAS -- measure the voltage and current waveforms across the triac, and make sure that you're within the VO2223A's dV/dt(c) rating.